# How can I make a config file to import the same modules for multiple jest tests?

Tags: reactjs, config, jestjs, react-on-rails

I have tests for jest written in jsx files with these same lines of code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

How can I make a config file to include these every time instead of writing these in my test file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will still need to do

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
```

in your unit tests since your tests need to use `React` and `shallow` but you can move

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

into a separate file and configure that file to be run before each test.

If you bootstrapped your app using `create-react-app` v4 or higher and haven't ejected then [you can put that code in `src/setupTests.js`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#initializing-test-environment)

Otherwise you can [configure `Jest` to run it as a `setupTestFrameworkScriptFile`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setuptestframeworkscriptfile-string)